# Валидация таблицы с динамическими строками

Tags: angularjs, валидация

У меня есть таблица с динамически добавляемыми строками. Когда я нажимаю "add row" клонируется изначальная (первая, дефолтная) строка. Вместе также клонируется ID поля.

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    var copy = angular.copy($scope.item[0]);
    $scope.item.push(copy)
  }
```

валидацию провожу таким вот образом:

```
ng-class='{"is-invalid": tableForm[field.id].$invalid}'
```

и в связи с одинаковыми name если в колонке есть не валидное поле - остальные тоже будут подсвечиваться. Как вариант можно было бы при клонировании менять ID, но к сожалению этот вариант не подходит для проекта. Еще один вариант пробовал это добавить в `<tr> ng-form` и динамически менять имя `ng-form="{{row + $index}}"`, но webstorm сразу же подсветил это как ошибку, скорее всего потому что название формы должно быть статическое. Подскажите как не меняя id при клонировании настроить правильно валидацию? [Пример плнкр](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKXBXArCmoxVnmS6ubbB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как форма одна, а строк много в объекте tableForm будет только *одно* свойство с ключом равным id.

Для решения можно просто дописывать к id номер строки:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = [{
    field: [{
      name: 'Bird',
      id: 'littleBird',
      value: 'Dove'
    }, {
      name: 'Dog',
      id: 'bigGreyDog',
      value: 'Lucky'
    }, {
      name: 'Cat',
      id: 'tinyKitty',
      value: 'Fluffy'
    }, {
      name: 'Bug',
      id: 'uglyBug',
      value: 'Buggy'
    }]
  }]

  $scope.addRow = function() {
    var copy = angular.copy($scope.item[0]);
    $scope.item.push(copy)
  }

  $scope.removeRow = function(index) {
    $scope.item.splice(index, 1)
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 70px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  <h1>table</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat='item in item[0].field'>{{item.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-form='tableForm'>
      <tr ng-repeat='row in item' ng-init="rowIndex=$index">
        <td ng-repeat='field in row.field'>
          <input type="text" ng-model='field.value' name='{{field.id+rowIndex}}' required ng-class='{"is-invalid": tableForm[field.id+rowIndex].$invalid}'>
        </td>
        <td ng-if='$index !== 0' style='color:red;cursor:pointer' ng-click='removeRow($index)'>X</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button ng-click='addRow()'>add row</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, т.к. форма одна и дублей много подсвечиваются все.

Как вариант дублировать по индексу на каждый ряд `ng-form`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xQYACcytuyXIGn7bYTev?p=preview